# Unsetting the Proxy in Conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I know we can set the proxy in conda using the following command

```
conda config --set proxy_servers.http  <proxy>
conda config --set proxy_servers.https  <proxy>
```

But how do I unset these proxy servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the documentation of `conda config`:

```
Config Modifiers:
  --get [KEY [KEY ...]]
                        Get a configuration value.
  --append KEY VALUE    Add one configuration value to the end of a list key.
  --prepend KEY VALUE, --add KEY VALUE
                        Add one configuration value to the beginning of a list
                        key.
  --set KEY VALUE       Set a boolean or string key
  --remove KEY VALUE    Remove a configuration value from a list key. This
                        removes all instances of the value.
  --remove-key KEY      Remove a configuration key (and all its values).
  --stdin               Apply configuration information given in yaml format
                        piped through stdin.
```

So

```
conda config --remove-key proxy_servers.http
conda config --remove-key proxy_servers.https
```

should do the trick !

Comment: Found out after some research but thanks for the answer

Comment: But it won't work for me: `CondaKeyError: 'proxy_servers': key 'proxy_servers' is not in the config file`.

Comment: @Shayan the key "proxy_servers" is not present in your config file as stated ! The `conda config` command is modifying the file ".condarc" in your HOME. You can also edit this file manually.

Comment: @EricC., I found the file you mentioned, but it contains nothing about proxies. It contains: `channels`, `channel_priority`, and `report_errors`.

Comment: @Shayan then you probably don't have any "proxy_servers" set. What makes you think you should remove those "proxy_servers" settings from your conda? ENV variables may also impact conda: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/proxy/

Comment: @EricC., *"What makes you think you should remove those "proxy_servers" settings from your conda?"* Actually, I tried to modify proxy_servers a while ago, however, I can't remember whether I succeed. But the problem is where I can't update packages within a conda env using `conda update --all` anymore, and I wonder if it's because of the recent modification on relevant proxies variables.